# How to mock writer in Spring Batch Junit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-batch

I am testing Spring Batch application using Junit:

This is my job xml configuration:

```
    <!-- parse queue -->
    <batch:step id="parseQueue">

        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk

            reader="readQueue"
            processor="processQueue"
            writer="customItemWriter"
            commit-interval="100">

            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>

    </batch:step>
```

I am testing the "parseQueue" step.

I am using JobLauncherTestUtils to test a step like below:

jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("parseQueue");

The problem is it runs the entires step code. I mean reader, processor and writer.
I want to skip the execution of Writer.

Is there a way to do it?

Any suggestion on mocking "Writer" in Spring Batch?

I have tried to mock the Writer. It doesn't mock and the real Writer implementation gets called. Usually, it would have worked, but it just doesn't seem to be working with Spring Batch.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code of my Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/job/qhandler-job.xml",
        "classpath:/spring/qhandler-applicationContext.xml" })
public class TestReader {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Mock
    CustomItemWriter writer;

    @InjectMocks
    private ReadQueueMsgFromWs reader;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testReader() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException, Exception
    {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("parseQueue");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does `writer="customItemWriter"` points to a mock? Can you show how the `customItemWriter` bean is defined in your context?

Comment: show your test bro, lets see whats going on in there.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine No, it doesn't points to a mock. CustomItemWriter implements Spring Batch's ItemWriter.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Added the test code.

Comment: IMO it is easier for you to use a stub rather than a mock.

Answer (score 0):

In an IT scenario, you use `@MockBean` to stub a container managed bean.

Try this:

```
@MockBean
CustomItemWriter writer;

@Autowired
private ReadQueueMsgFromWs reader;
```

you also do not need to use the `@InjectMocks` here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Maciej. But this doesn't work. I suspect  it needs a some specific code for Spring Batch? As Reader/Processor/Writer is being called by spring batch container and not by the class/method I am testing.

Comment: can you add a stack trace or part of it?

Comment: I do not get an error/exception, it just calls the methods of the mocked writer class.(which I want to avoid)